# import python into pymel

Tags: python, scripting, maya, mel, pymel

I was working on my Auto-Rig script and noticed that the code was getting long making it hard to read and focus on one part. I was looking into importing a python file and call the functions inside the python file that was imported. Can't seem to find a way to import the file could someone help me with that.

Comment: write thefile.py and then in your script `import thefile`. Use functions calling `thefile.afunction()`

Comment: the best way is invest some minutes for reading the python documentation about [inheritance, private variables and Class local-references][1], its fundamental to understand that a "object" in any oop language should have a data and behavior,
[1]: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you create python module with your Python file and then do from MEL file:

```
python "import my_python_module";

string $pycommand = "my_python_module.my_function(param1, "+ $mel_string_param1 +",\"" + $mel_string_param2 + "\")";

string $result= `python $pycommand`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the functions you want to include in your module as a python file. (tip: do not start your python filename with digits).

In my example `myModule.py` contains:

```
def myFunc1():
    print 'myFunc1 is called'
    pass

def myFunc2():    
    print 'myFunc2 is called'
    return
```

Now save the file in a folder. My example Python file path is:

`d:\projects\python\myModule.py`

Now in your Maya session script editor, enter:

```
import sys
import os

modulePath = os.path.realpath(r'd:\projects\python\myModule.py')
moduleName = 'myModule'

if modulePath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(modulePath)

try:
    reload(moduleName)
except:
    exec('import %s' % moduleName)
```

Your module should be imported.

Now call `myFunc1()` from `myModule`:

`myModule.myFunc1()`

This will give the output:

`myFunc1 is called`

Now we call `myFunc2()` from `myModule`:

`myModule.myFunc2()`

This will give the output:

`myFunc2 is called`

If we now update our `myModule.py` with a new function:

```
def myFunc3():    
        print 'myFunc3 is called'
        return
```

We only need to run that same code above to reload the updated module.

Now we can try the statement:

`myModule.myFunc3()`

... and get this output:

`myFunc3 is called`